# How to fix the error TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-cd

I created a code of tikzpicture in Geogebra, but when I try to run it I am getting this error

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
\T1/ptm/m/n/10
l.460 ...-20.0:380.0] {(\x,{sin((x°)*180/\pi)})};

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
24821 strings out of 480790
625143 string characters out of 2905174
1149710 words of memory out of 3000000
40387 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
598583 words of font info for 132 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
5000i,7n,9985p,744b,1555s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
I am providing a complete code to

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
    \usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=7in, top=1in, bottom=0.8in, twocolumn, twoside]{geometry}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{{Graphics/}}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{mathptmx}
    \usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
    %\usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    %\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
    %\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    %\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    %\usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage[arrow,frame,matrix]{xy}
    %\usepackage{fixltx2e}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
    \newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}[section]
    \newtheorem{lem}[Thm]{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{pro}[Thm]{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{de}[Thm]{Definition}
    \newtheorem{re}[Thm]{Remark}
    \newtheorem{ex}[Thm]{Example}
    \newtheorem{cor}[Thm]{Corollary}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-20.0,
xmax=380.0,
ymin=-1.3,
ymax=1.3,
xtick={-0.0,30.0,...,360.0},
ytick={-1.0,0.0,...,1.0},]
\addplot[line width=1.0pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=-20.0:380.0] {(\x,{sin((x°)*180/pi)})};
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (0.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (28.593337309363406,0.4785897576737861) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (60.,0.8660254037844386) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (90.,1.) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (121.46204311152749,0.852986118252905) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (149.57825679475147,0.5063610434377226) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=uuuuuu] (180.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (209.2187100621963,-0.4881446877366753) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (239.89094317116792,-0.8650721352155233) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (270.,-1.) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (299.5313964386128,-0.870085731338953) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (328.49961659708595,-0.5225042702680185) circle (2.0pt);
\draw [fill=black] (360.,0.) circle (2.0pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should type `{sin(deg(x))}` instead of `{(\x,{sin((x°)*180/pi)})}`

Comment: What is that  `° ` doing there (in the function you're trying to plot)? Additionally I don't think scriptsize does anything here.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% change degree to radian
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{20*pi/180}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{380*pi/180}
\draw[->] (-\a-.5,0)--(\b+.5,0) node[above]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node[left]{$y$};
\draw[gray,thin,dashed] (0,1)--+(0:\b) (0,-1)--+(0:\b) (pi/2,0)--+(90:1) (3*pi/2,0)--+(-90:1);
\draw[smooth,red]  plot[domain=-\a:\b] (\x,{sin(\x r)});
\path
(0,0) node[above left]{$O$}
(0,1) node[left]{$1$}
(0,-1) node[left]{$-1$}
(pi/2,0) node[below]{$\frac{\pi}{2}$}
(3*pi/2,0) node[above]{$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}
(pi,0) node[above right]{$\pi$}
(2*pi,0) node[below right]{$2\pi$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```